# OpenSSH terminates other sessions on the same shared connection

Tags: openssh

Why does OpenSSH_8.4p1 terminate other sessions that share the same connection when ProxyCommand is used? Is there some way to prevent this?

Note: This behavior does not seem to happen if the ProxyCommand argument is omitted.

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Kill any existing shared connections to localhost:

```
ssh -o ControlPath=/tmp/%C -O exit 127.0.0.1 2>/dev/null
ssh -o ControlPath=/tmp/%C -O exit localhost 2>/dev/null
```

2. Run the following command twice in parallel each in a different terminal:

```
ssh -F none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/tmp/%C -o ControlPersist=1d \
  -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p 127.0.0.1' \
  localhost 'sleep 3600'
```

3. Interrupt the first ssh process with SIGINT by typing control-C.

## Expected behavior

- Only the SIGINT'ed process terminates.
- Other process continues to run unaffected.

## Actual behavior

- Both processes are terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only the SIGINT'ed process terminates.

"Process" is a false premise. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> [sends `SIGINT` to the foreground process *group* of the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149756/108618). A process group may include more than one process.

Then this is relevant:

> `ProxyCommand`
> Specifies the command to use to connect to the server. The command string extends to the end of the line, and is executed using the user's shell `exec` directive to avoid a lingering shell process.
> […]

<sup>([source](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand))</sup>

The command is executed locally in the same process group as the main `ssh`. In your example the command is `ssh …` but in general it may be anything. In any case the command is not aware of `ControlMaster` and `ControlPersist` you used for the main `ssh`.

When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, each process in the foreground process group gets `SIGINT`. The "main" `ssh` exits without affecting the socket in the `ControlPath` because in case of `ControlPersist` other than `no` this socket is from the start handled by *yet another* `ssh` process which is deliberately spawned in its own process group, this allows it to survive. In this context you may call it the truly main `ssh`.

The unexpected behavior is because the command specified with `ProxyCommand` gets spawned in the foreground process group and it does get `SIGINT` along with the `ssh` you want to interrupt. The command reacts to the signal as if it would normally do. In your case the command terminates upon `SIGINT`. And because the command was supposed to relay all data, the master connection (the truly main `ssh`) is now useless. It terminates along with all dependent `ssh` processes.

So the original `ssh` does additional work to ensure `ssh` handling the master connection (and the socket) survives <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but it doesn't do this for the command specified with `ProxyCommand` which is equally important. I think you can call it a bug.

It probably would be better if the command specified in `ProxyCommand` was spawned by the immune `ssh` in *its* process group. I haven't analyzed this thoroughly enough. Anyway, for now it's not the case, the command is spawned it the process group that is the foreground process group at the time you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, so it gets `SIGINT`.

A workaround is to make the command immune to `SIGINT`. Inside `ProxyCommand` you cannot use `trap` directly because `ProxyCommand` uses `exec` automatically and `exec trap …` makes no sense and won't work. You need yet another shell:

```
ssh -F none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/tmp/%C -o ControlPersist=1d \
  -o ProxyCommand='sh -c "trap \"\" INT; exec ssh -W %h:%p 127.0.0.1"' \
  localhost 'sleep 3600'
```

My tests indicate that being immune to `SIGINT` will not prevent this inner `ssh` from exiting when the time comes and the master connection should terminate because of the finite `ControlPersist` setting.